# Emacs d-mode cannot handle backquoted backslashes

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, d, string-literals

Currently Emacs https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode cannot correctly highlight

```
`\`
```

because it doesn't understand that single backslashes are 
self-contained in such a *raw* string literal.

I believe this extract from d-mode.el

```
(defvar d-mode-syntax-table nil
  "Syntax table used in d-mode buffers.")
(or d-mode-syntax-table
    (setq d-mode-syntax-table
     (let ((table (funcall (c-lang-const c-make-mode-syntax-table d))))
       ;; Make it recognize D `backquote strings`
       (modify-syntax-entry ?` "\"" table)

       ;; Make it recognize D's nested /+ +/ comments
       (modify-syntax-entry ?+  ". 23n"   table)
       table)))
```

is highly related to this problem. Ideas on how to fix this anyone?

See also: http://forum.dlang.org/post/kqzbgawuzyemcyjnsuin@forum.dlang.org

Comment: If syntax tables are insufficient, it may be worth looking into `syntax-propertize-rules` and the `syntax-propertize-function` variable, which provide more flexibility by using regular expressions to describe syntax.  Unfortunately they only exist in Emacs 24 and up, IIRC.

Comment: python-mode has the same problem with r"\". I think that what @JonO is the only way.

Comment: Perhaps add this as an issue on the D-Mode GitHub repository? https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode/issues

Comment: Pull requests fixing bugs always welcome! https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode/pulls

Comment: I guess we should use `syntax-propertize-rules` conditionally only for Emacs 24+.

Comment: Can anyone give some brief hints on how to use these new Emacs 24.4+ features? I can't find any good introductory examples that explain how these things work.

Answer (score 3):

What Jon O. says: use a `syntax-propertize-function`.  E.g.

```
(setq-local syntax-propertize-function
            (syntax-propertize-rules ("`\\(\\\\\\)`" (1 "."))))
```

Comment: Could somebody please explain shortly what this mean? Is this the code I should add to d-mode to make things work?

Comment: Yes, inside the `d-mode` function (probably defined with `define-derived-mode`).

Answer (score 1):

Fix has now been committed to the Git repository with required Emacs minimum of 24.3 as that has been tested on Debian Sid.